# map triple of unsigned int's to double -- is it the most optimal/efficient way?

Tags: c++, optimization, dictionary

I face the following task: 
map triplet of unsigned int's to a value, which is either zero or positive (double); And be able for a given triplet obtain the double or say that it's actually zero;

I have the following simplification:
 first (let's call it I) and second (let's cal it J) ints are in known ranges (from zero to IMAX and JMAX).
For the third index (K), I know an estimate of triplets (third index is scattered), say ESTIMATE; 
During calculation the number of triplets growths, more precisely, for a given I and K, the number of third indices can increase.

So far I see the following solution:

keep vector of vectors of map:

```
vector< vector < map <unsinged int, unsigned int>>>  tri_map_;
//^I    ^J            ^K            ^index
```

if 'index' is not zero, obtain the value from supplementary vector:

```
vector< double> values;
values[index];
```

The whole thing to be initialized as:

```
tri_map_.resize(IMAX);
for (int i=0;i<IMAX;++i) tri_map_[i].resize(JMAX);
```

What do you think about that solution? Is there a better way to do it?

The thing I don't like is that it seems I can't do something like 'reserve' for 
the map. Is there a way to try to allocate enough memory (cos I have an estimate for the third index) and check if there is enough memory for that? Apart from that I'm satisfied with it.

EDIT1:
IMAX ~ hundrets
JMAX ~ 10^5

EDIT2:
trying to incorporate the solution of sehe, but for 
unordered_set and for pair;
So, that's where I have a problem `specialization of ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::tr1::hash’ in different namespace` :
...
EDIT3: the following works, will investigate its speed.
Thanks everyone for suggestions and advices!

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <tr1/unordered_set>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <tr1/array>
#include <iostream>

struct pair_int {
    unsigned int first;
    unsigned int second;

    bool operator< (pair_int const& o) const {
        if ( first < o.first )
        return true;
        if ( first > o.first )
          return false;
        return second < o.second;
   }
   bool operator==(pair_int const& o) const {
        return ( (first==o.first)&&(second==o.second) );
   }
};

namespace std {
namespace tr1 {
    template<> struct hash<pair_int> {
        unsigned int operator()(pair_int const& key) const {
            return  ~key.first + 17u*key.second;
        }
    };
}
}

class pair_storage {
public:
    pair_storage() {};  
    ~pair_storage();
    ....
private:
    pair_int pair_ij_;
    std::map<pair_int,double>::iterator  pairMapIterator_;
    std::vector< std::map<pair_int,double> >  pairMapVector_;
    std::vector< std::tr1::unordered_set< pair_int > > pairMapVectorZero_;
};
```

Can't compile it with `-std=c++0x` cos I have some problems in some parts of big code...

Comment: a triplet of `unsigned int`'s will typically have 93 significant bits, while a non-negative `double` has only 63 bits. So even your best map will be multi-valued. Is this desired?

Comment: Since IMAX and JMAX are known in advance consider using a single vector with derived index (e.g. idx = i * JMAX + j)

Comment: what is the requirement of your map? The most simple one, which satisfies what you've said, is to map *all* triples to zero.

Comment: @Walter sorry, i don't understand what you mean by 'even your best map will be multi-valued'

Comment: @alexm Thanks for the advice. Fully agree

Comment: @Walter all possible triplets to zero is too much memory; It's like a sparse matrix, there are very few triplets for which I need to know if its zero or something. That sparsity is in 3rd index

Comment: @Denis multivalued means that different triples give the same `double`

Comment: @Walter ahh, i see. That is excluded. Different triplets give different doubles. (apart from zeros)

Comment: @Walter the number of non-zero triplets in that sparse construction is way less than the zero one, that's why i introduce index to store actual doubles and give index=0 to those which are zero.

Comment: @Denis How is this excluded? The total space of triplets has 93 bits and hence is bigger than that of doubles.

Comment: @Walter by 'excluded' i mean, that for each triplet I'm interested in (that is still sub-space of all triplets) the value is either zero, or something. If it is non-zero, then the double it is unique.

Comment: How do you benchmark your code (or any suggestion which may be given to this answer)? Any discussions about relative performance of any two solutions is useless without agreeing on a benchmark first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me you are looking for

- [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)
- [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)
- [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- [std::unordered_multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)

Here is a simple example of using std::unordered_multimap (which will require the specialization of `std::hash<>` for your key type, and is therefore the slightly more involved way to write it):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct triplet 
{ 
    unsigned a,b,c;
    bool operator< (triplet const& o) const { return std::tie(a,b,c) < std::tie(o.a,o.b,o.c); }
    bool operator==(triplet const& o) const { return std::tie(a,b,c) ==std::tie(o.a,o.b,o.c); }
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<triplet> {
        unsigned int operator()(triplet const& key) const { 
            return  ~key.a + 17u*key.b + 17u*key.c; // totally made that up, could be better, I suppose
        }
    };
}

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, triplet const& key) {
    return os << '[' << key.a << ',' << key.b << ',' << key.c << ']';
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_multimap<triplet, double> map;

    // insert items dynamically
    map.insert({ triplet{ /*I*/ 1, /*J*/ 2, /*K*/ 3 },  0.1 } );
    map.insert({ triplet{ /*I*/ 4, /*J*/ 5, /*K*/ 6 },  0.2 } );
    map.insert({ triplet{ /*I*/ 7, /*J*/ 8, /*K*/ 9 },  0.3 } );
    map.insert({ triplet{ /*I*/ 1, /*J*/ 2, /*K*/ 0 },  0.4 } ); // duplicate (I,J) ok

    map.insert({ triplet{ /*I*/ 1, /*J*/ 2, /*K*/ 0 }, 0.5 } );

    assert(0 == map.count(triplet {1,5,6}));
    assert(1 == map.count(triplet {4,5,6}));

    auto range = map.equal_range(triplet { 1,2,0 });
    for (auto it=range.first; it!=range.second; ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
}
```

Output (as seen on **http://ideone.com/pm8Oz**):

```
[1,2,0]: 0.4
[1,2,0]: 0.5
```

Comment: thank you very much for a detailed example. Do you think unordered_map is faster that just map in terms of insertion and search?

Comment: @Denis Depends on the usage patterns. I'd think a tree based ('ordered') maybe quicker in small sizes, especially when entries need to be traversed in ascending order (which is a 'side-effect' of `std::(multi_)map`). In essence, you just profile to measure the difference.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to specialize `std::hash` for a standard type (in this case `triplet`). Even if you are allowed, consider the principle of "what if everyone did it?" to which the answer is an ODR violation because they won't all use the same hash function. Rather, you could define your own type as a wrapper of `tuple<unsigned,unsigned,unsigned>` and use that as the key, or you could supply your own hasher to your `unordered_multimap` instead of letting it use the default `std::hash<KeyType>`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oops. Yes you are right. You can specialize std::hash, but only for user defined types. Actually, I thought the std::hash<tuple<>> was mandated in the standard, but apparently it's not. This is a bit of a usability issue with std::tuple then. **Edit** Fixed

Comment: @sehe: I certainly agree that it's a usability issue. Especially since I use Python a lot, and commonly use tuples as dictionary keys, so I feel like C++11 has short-changed me. Maybe for some reason the committee didn't want to make a call on how hashes should be combined?

Comment: @SteveJessop I reckon it's an oversight. _'Luckily'_, there is a law against specializing it for std::tuple, so the next standard can include it :)

Comment: @sehe I'm trying to introduce your solution with a hash. I have this error: `my_map.h:40:19: error: ‘hash’ is not a template
my_map.h:40:34: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘hash’`. That's for `template<> struct hash<...` Do you have any idea what's it?

Comment: @sehe EDITED the original message. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Triple
{
    unsigned int A;
    unsigned int B;
    unsigned int C;
};

map<Triple, double> mapping;
```

Comment: i don't see why that would be faster and consume less memory than vector<unordered_set> for zeros; + vector<map<unsinged int,double> for non-zeros

Comment: @Denis - And I don't see why it wouldn't be faster and/or consume more memory either.  I do not see eitherway because -- I am unable to!  I haven't measured anything yet.  Peter's code most clearly expresses what the intent is, and for that, he gets a +1.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps I think one knows it from the O(logN). If I join all the triplets in one map, the search is of O(log IMAX*JMAX*...), but if I keep 'personal' map for each pair of I-J, the search if of O(log ...), which is definitely smaller than the one above. I would say no tests are needed in such a case.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps another point I realized is that in such an approach i need to store a lot of zeros. It seems to me that a combination of two vectors of map and unordered_set is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question "is it the most optimal/efficient way?":

Try using `hash_map` or `unordered_map`; that might be faster than `map` (or may be not, depending on your use case).

Regarding the question "Is there a way to try to allocate enough memory...?":

You can use `unordered_map::max_load_factor` to adjust memory/performance trade-off; this is just like preallocation.

Oh, and you can also use `unordered_set` to store elements that map to zero. That might reduce memory consumption for no performance cost.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I only new now which one is faster? :) With regards to unordered_set, that will indeed save a lot of memory. Thanks for that idea. Then, I don't actually need any index vector, but I would need to do to searches, one in unordered_set and one in some kind of map of K -> double